# fax-number validation with regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, grails, groovy

I have phone-number(fax-number) like

```
(916) 714-9929 
+49 (89) 51 7771-25 
225.336.0411 direct 
(225) 389-7656 Fax
```

want to regular expression validation like

```
if (phoneNumber.matches("\\d{8}") || phoneNumber.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}") || phoneNumber.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\)[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}") || phoneNumber.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}\\s(x|(ext))\\d{3,5}")){
    log.info("cmd pass 2")
    println "validate phone numbers of format \\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4} && \\(\\d{3}\\)[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4} "
    return true;
}else {
    return "MyFaxInvalidFaxNumber"
}
```

Comment: I am using above regular expression for validating : ((916) 714-9929, 225.336.0411 ) this two fax-number want solution for +49 (89) 51 7771-25

Comment: Does that not work? You should print out the result of each match to see which regex isn't working correctly: `println phoneNumber.matches("\d{8}")`.

Comment: Or are you just looking for a better solution?

Comment: As per my above comment i want to allow ( +49 (89) 51 7771-25) number which is not validating in current code. if is there any combined solution for defined fax-number plz. suggest me

Comment: Can't you just use [Googles libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) rather than trying to create your own

Comment: I am not getting your point and i want to developed my own logic for validation not use any plugin for that

Comment: the following link : http://www.journaldev.com/641/regular-expression-phone-number-validation-in-java
having solution which i want could any one make regular expression for fax-number like (+49 (89) 51 7771-25 )